# Google Sheets: How do I look up multiple values in another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, formula, lookup

The scenario I am faced with is kind of an odd one. Basically, I am designing a Google Sheet for work that will allow the employees to log their tech support phone calls and then a report will automatically update on another page, keeping a collective tally of sorts of all the activity on a particular day.

What I am trying to do is write a function that searches another sheet for a particular date and, if that date is found, sum a particular column of values for that day only. There are pictures attached that should help explain the problem.

Basically, I am trying to write a general equation in the cell reading "FALSE" that will look up the date of that row (in this case 1/1/2017) in the "Spendgo Minutes" sheet. If that date were to be found somewhere on that sheet (not necessarily at the top of the sheet), the "Minutes Gained" column would be summed up, but for that date only (not the entire column). Here is my running formula right now that has errors:

=IF(COUNTIF('Spendgo Tally'!$A$3:$A,$B7),'Spendgo Tally'!$G3)

Does anyone know how this might be possible? Feel free to ask any clarifying questions.

[image: This is the general tally where the dates will be looked up.]

[image: This is the totals page that I am trying to write the formula on.]

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for SUMIF

```
  = SUMIF('Spendgo Tally'!$A$3:$A,$B7,'Spendgo Tally'!$G3:$G)
```

Comment: If this helped, Click ☑  on the left of this post.